# spring boot + spring data jpa @query invaild

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

spring boot 2.0

spring data jpa 2

```
@Modifying
@Query(name = "delete from User a where age=?1 and username=?1")
void deleteByAge(int i);
```

`@Query` is invalid. Did not execute the JPQL I wrote

**question 2：**

```
@Modifying
@Query(name = "delete from User a where age=?1 and username=?1")
void dByAge(int i);
```

spring boot startup exception:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method
>   public abstract void
>   com.unuobi.testboot.repository.UserRepository.dByAge(int)! No property
>   dByAge found for type User!

Comment: Try "User" instead of "User a"

Answer (score 0):

**✔ @Query(value="select ....")**

> ✖ @Query(name="select ....")

must be value ,

Answer (score 0):

Use this as JPQL Query required age and username so both has to pass in your method , whatever type username is and they should be always in sequence they used in `@Query`:

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from User a where age=?1 and username=?1")
void deleteByAge(int age, String username);
```

Or named query can be:

```
void deleteByAgeAndUsername(int age, String username);
```

make sure you have age and username in User entity.